# Symfony router - one route name for more paths based on host+locale

Tags: php, routes, symfony

is possible create symfony route with one name (e.g. "contact") and more paths based on host? And this route sets `_locale` by host too.

I need it for simple usage `{{ path('contact') }}` in template.

Example:

```
contact:
     host:      example.com
     path:      /contact
     defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Contact:index, _locale: en }

     host:      example.cz
     path:      /kontakt
     defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Contact:index, _locale: cs }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JMSI18nRoutingBundle for this. In this [page](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration) you can find the same case.